# How would a debugger running in Linux/Windows read the PC register on ARM32 & Aarch64?

Tags: debugging, arm, cpu-registers, arm64

How would a debugger running in Linux/Windows read the PC register on ARM32 & Aarch64?
How to access Instruction Register Value?

How to use ptrace to retrieve the PC register of child process on Linux?
How to use GetThreadContext to retrieve the PC register from context structure of a child process on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: what is it you are trying to do?    intel and at&t are assembly language syntax nuances variants for x86 and have nothing to do with arm (nor x86 instructions either). much less the pc

Comment: define debugger in this context

Comment: I am trying to adapt some code of a Pascal debugger done for x86 cpu.  Now, thanks to you, I know that intel or at&t assemblers are not compatible for arm.  So, back to the initial question, how to do and with what tool ( assembler for arm ? or something else ? ) to read the PC register on a ARM32 or Aarch64 CPU ?

Comment: Hello.  I have updated the comment of the question.  Maybe it is more clear now.

Comment: You should probably ask about Linux and Windows in separate posts, as the answers would be completely different.

Comment: @Nate Ha, ok.  Linux is more important at the moment but Windows has (is busy to have) ARM as target too, so I want to be ready for that.  When all is working for Linux, I will do a other post.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptrace(2)` has a `PTRACE_GETREGS` option that reads all the general-purpose registers of the tracee, into a `struct user_regs_struct` as defined in `<sys/user.h>`.  For AArch64, this struct has an array of size 31 for registers x0 through x30, as well as separate fields for sp, pc and pstate.  So you could do (untested):

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

struct user_regs_struct regs;
if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) < 0)
    die();
printf("pc is %#llx\n", regs.pc);
```

For ARM32 it looks like the struct is called `struct user_regs` instead, which is just an array of size 18.  I would guess that it is r0 through r15 (where r15 is pc), then maybe `pstate` and something else?  You'd have to check kernel or GDB sources to confirm.  So you can *probably* do (very untested):

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

struct user_regs regs;
if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) < 0)
    die();
printf("pc is %#lx\n", regs.uregs[15]);
```

Comment: Excellent!  Many thanks, I will test it tonight.  Write you later.

Comment: I've confirmed that this is the correct answer.