# Getting/setting registers for arm32 executable on aarch64

Tags: c, arm, cpu-registers, arm64, ptrace

My goal is to use `ptrace` to set the program counter (and other registers) of a process running a 32-bit ARM executable on a 64-bit processor.

If this was a 64-bit executable, then I could use the `pc` field of `struct user_pt_regs` (defined in asm/ptrace.h).

Which structure would I use for a 32-bit executable?  I see `struct user_regs` (in sys/user.h) defined as

```c
struct user_regs {
    unsigned long uregs[18];
};
```

I read the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70334705/how-would-a-debugger-running-in-linux-windows-read-the-pc-register-on-arm32-aa) (though the author admitted that this was an educated guess) which suggests the use of `uregs[15]` from `struct user_regs`.  However, would that still work in my case since I actually have a 64-bit system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when running on a 64-bit processor, `ptrace` hands back the *effective* 32-bit registers.  To confirm this, consider the following two executables (for brevity's sake, I've omitted the header files and error checking):

test.c

```c
int main()
{
    printf("PID = %li\n", (long)getpid());
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

attacher.c

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int expected_size;
    pid_t pid;
    struct {
        uint32_t r[18];
    } regs;
    struct iovec iov;

    pid = atoi(argv[1]); // Yes, I know I should use strtol.  However, this suffices for this example.
    ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);

    iov.iov_base = &regs;
    iov.iov_len = expected_size = sizeof(regs);
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGSET, pid, NT_PRSTATUS, &iov);
    if ( iov.iov_len != expected_size ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected size (%zu instead of %u)\n", iov.iov_len, expected_size);
        // abort
    }
    printf("PC is 0x%x\n", regs.r[15]);

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the first into a 32-bit executable and the second into a 64-bit executable.

Taking the output from the attacher, I looked up the address in `/proc/<pid>/maps` and saw that it lands in the executable section of libc (corresponding to `pause`).

Comment: I wonder how this works for `PTRACE_GETREGS` in which the length of the buffer isn't specified.  If a debugger thinks it is debugging a 32-bit process and allocates an appropriate buffer, but the process is actually 64-bit, won't the buffer be overrun?  That sounds like something that could be exploitable in case of a privileged tracer and a malicious tracee (not an unusual combination).

Comment: Wouldn't the debugger be able to determine the size of the registers from the ELF header?

Comment: The ELF header of which binary?  The tracer may see that it originally exec'd a 32-bit binary, but in the meantime the tracee may have exec'd some other binary.  You would have to be doing `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` as well and refresh the headers from `/proc/XXX/exe` when hit, so as to be sure to always know the current bitness.  Even at that, I am not sure if there could still be loopholes.

Comment: Well, you do set `iov.iov_len` to the size you're expecting.

Comment: For `PTRACE_GETREGSET`, yes.  I'm talking about `PTRACE_GETREGS` which takes a pointer directly to the buffer instead of a `struct iovec` and so has no way to specify the buffer size.